# How to call Jmeter Counter Reference Name variable incrementing one

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In my testplan, I'm using Counter config element and have configured start = 1, increment = 1, maximum = 4 and the ReferenceName = loopCount.

And in a sampler, I have used Json Extractor as well where I want to set the

```
Match No: ${loopCount} + 1
```

since in the Json file I'm extracting always the first match is null.

Unfortunately I think I can't give it like

```
${loopCount} + 1.
```

Is there any work around for this.. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) after the **Counter config element** with the below code in the code area:

```
int Counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("loopCount"));

vars.put("Increment", String.valueOf(Counter+1));
```

And now you can use the variable `${Increment}` as the Match No.

**OR**

You can use `${__intSum(${loopCount},1)}` which will add 1 to the value of loopCount variable directly.